# How to prevent react-table sort and search reset

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table-v7

In this official example, table sorting and searching resets on blur of any editable field.[https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/master/examples/kitchen-sink?file=/src/App.js](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/master/examples/kitchen-sink)
How can I prevent that? I want sort and search to stay the same, even if someone edits the data.

Comment: what do you mean by `on blur of any editable field`?

Comment: @HagaiHarari thanks for looking into this. if you sort data (say by first name) and click on any editable field (say any first names) and click again on any other editable field (say any last names), sort resets to original. I want to prevent that.

Comment: As per SO guidelines, while is fine to *also* include a CodeBox, or any relevant link, ALL necessary information, data, & code, in the form of a minimally viable complete example, MUST be embedded in the post itself. Accordingly, please edit to paste code into your Q to avoid closure by the SO community. In addition to markdown code blocks, you can use SO code snippets if your code consists of HTML, JS, CSS. Welcome to So. All the Best. See more info in the SO [help](StackOverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 8):

When using sortBy you can set this property to false

> autoResetSortBy: Boolean
>
> - Defaults to true
> - When true, the sortBy state will automatically reset if any of the following conditions are met: data is changed
> - To disable, set to false

https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/api/useSortBy

The same thing for filtering

> autoResetFilters: Boolean
>
> - Defaults to true
> - When true, the filters state will automatically reset if any of the following  conditions are met: data is changed
> - To disable, set to false

https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/api/useFilters

Also see this FAQ https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/faq#how-do-i-stop-my-table-state-from-automatically-resetting-when-my-data-changes

**Edit**
For completeness, one can also set `autoResetGlobalFilter` on the global filter: [see documentation](https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/api/useGlobalFilter).